# Access clarification within class/struct

Tags: c++

```
class Axes
{

public:

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

};
```

In search of my curiosity, i have written the example shown beneath. Now my question is about the `axes.x`, is the `x` variable in this case accessed in 2 steps or in 1 step, considering the fact that `x` is within a class? In other words, dose the `axes` variable get accessed prior to the accessing the `x` variable, or is `axes.x` considered as single reference of its own after compile?

```
Axes axes;
std::cout << axes.x;
```

Update: I just for some reason keep thinking that after it was compiled that `x` would be accessed by its own memory address without having to go to the memory address of the `axes`.

Thank you so much. ^^

Comment: The term "dereference" applies to pointers and pointer-like objects. There are no pointers here, so no dereferences.

Comment: Because of that, I don't even know what the question is...

Comment: okey i will change the word... to accessed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the question is because there is no deferencing here (that's a term used for pointers)...

But let me give you a different answer than the posted ones:

Since `axes` is a local variable, the compiler knows it's exact address, it also knows the exact layout of the struct, so it can directly access `x` within it. The compiled code doesn't have to "access" `axes` first.

This is, of course, what happens in practice...

Comment: You get my new vote Karoly! I had strong belief about `x` being accessed directly after compile and as you say, it should be as so in practice... I have corrected my understanding about the home and the room thinking, because it applies prior to compile by may not apply post compile. Wow that was interesting. Thanks again. ^^

Answer (score 1):

The `.` is an operator (member access, not overloadable), so the expression before the dot is evaluated first, and then used to access the member. You could also say `foo().x` if `foo` returned a value of type `Axes`.

Comment: should not the that this isn't what people usually talk about when they mention dereferencing.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly i think there wont be any **dereferencing** since it's term used for pointers.

But for here,  `axes` is de-referenced first (in fact accessed as a local variable) and the expression after `.` is which in this case is `x`.

It's just like entering the home first via main door and then going to particular room after that.

Comment: I love your explanation about the home and the room. I think i understand now... I just for some reason kept thinking that after it was compiled that `x` would be accessed by its own memory address without having to go to the memory address of the `axes`.

Comment: Firstly Please Vote up for my answer (and mark accepted) 
Secondly, as per my knowledge it happens the way i added in my answer.

Comment: @8-bitButterfly: well, yes and no.. check my answer.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath which part of my answer do i have correct and is wrong.